# How to change the scrollbar to custom design? (avoid using the default browser look)

Tags: css, javascript, jquery

In Gmail, the new look, you can see there is a scroll-bar but it does not look same like browser scrollbar. How to make it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is [WebKit-specific restyling](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) of the browser's scrollbars. It doesn't apply to browsers based on other rendering engines. IE uses an entirely different set of style rules(there's a link in that post), and Firefox doesn't allow it at all normally, I believe. Mozilla, and the W3, consider the main browser scrollbars part of the OS GUI and so not something you should be messing with. You can get around these inconsistencies with scroller replacements like in Adam's suggestion, but the main scrollbars you're stuck with.

Comment: before asking, i did tested in Opera, Midori, Chrome, Firefox. (Except IE as i am Linux user).