# How to change scrollbar style in CSS?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change style scrollbar div for my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645316/change-style-scrollbar-div-for-my-site)
>   [css scrollbar style cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser)

I wanted to know how to change the style/look/image of the web scrollbar via CSS? Is it even possible?

Comment: It's currently possible (I believe) for webkit browsers only.

Comment: possible duplicate: [stackoverflow.com/questions/8562851/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562851/how-to-change-the-scrollbar-to-custom-design-avoid-using-the-default-browser-l)

Comment: Three "possible duplicate" comments, but no close wote? **WTF**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (in all browsers) with CSS.
It can be achieved with JavaScript though.

Comment: This is a comment though as it doesn't explain how to do this in JavaScript. It's not a full answer.

Comment: The question does not ask for a solution, it simply asks if it is possible. Therefore this qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this via CSS due to different browser engines/APIS. however you might want to use the [jQUERY](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) Solution

Comment: "Cross browser complexities" has nothing to do with it. There is no standard CSS for this. The reason is you would be changing the user's browser and that is not the purpose of CSS.

Comment: Ohh I think I should have mentioned different browser APIS actually

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard CSS for doing this though IE and Opera have proprietary means of doing so. The reason is you would be changing the user's browser look which is not the purpose of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A good post on how to do this for Safari/Chrome: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ Internet Explorer users don't deserve good design anyway, right? :P

Answer (score -1):

Here you go , this script degrades nicely in most browsers.

[JqueryScrollpane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html)